# Partitioning and Generating Functions

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am trying to solve $$P_k(x) = \sum_{n} p_k(n)x^n$$, which should give the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. So far, I have attempted to solve this simply by writing $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)...(1-x^k)}$$
since this should give the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into $k \geq 1$ parts.

How should I add the "exactly $k$ partitions" part of the problem to this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The generating function $P^{(\leq k)}(x)$ for the number of partitions which consists of parts *each* $\leq k$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> P^{(\leq k)}(x)&=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)\\
> &\qquad\cdot(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)\\
> &\qquad\cdot(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdots\\
> &\qquad\cdot(1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k}+\cdots)\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots(1-x^k)}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Note:** An interesting aspect is the number of partitions having parts *each* $\leq k$ is the same as the number of partitions having *at most* $k$ parts.

If we use *[Ferrer diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%5C%28number_theory%5C%29#Ferrers_diagram)* to visualise the situation (here with $k=3$ and $n=8$) we see that each partition containing parts each $\leq 3$ which is reflected at the main diagonal corresponds with a partition containing at most $3$ parts.

[image]

Since this correspondence is bijective the generating function is the same in both cases.

> We conclude a generating function $P^{(=k)}(x)$ for the number of partitions with *exactly* $k$ parts is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{P^{(=k)}(x)}&=P^{(\leq k)}(x)-P^{(\leq k-1)}(x)\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^k)}\\
> &\qquad-\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{k-1})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{k-1})}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^k}-1\right)\\
> &=\color{blue}{\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^k)}}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @pbgcho: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful! :-)